# Rename rows in numerical order in batches of 5

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a .txt file which looks like this:

```
LED time stamp      mean
1   14:28:04.832    0.000013    
2   14:28:06.926    0.000037    
3   14:28:09.066    0.000049    
4   14:28:11.191    0.000060    
5   14:28:13.347    0.000053    
1   14:28:15.504    0.000014    
2   14:28:17.738    0.000038    
3   14:28:19.910    0.000051    
4   14:28:22.113    0.000060    
5   14:28:24.269    0.000054    
1   14:28:26.394    0.000014
```

I would like to change the second column so that it ascend numerically and repeats every five rows, to look something like this:

```
LED  time stamp     mean
1      1         0.000013   
2      1         0.000037   
3      1         0.000049   
4      1         0.000060   
5      1         0.000053   
1      2         0.000014   
2      2         0.000038   
3      2         0.000051   
4      2         0.000060   
5      2         0.000054   
1      3         0.000014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `rep` function:

```
df <- data.frame(LED = rep(1:5, 3))

df$time_stamp <- rep(1:3, each = 5)

df
   LED time_stamp
1    1          1
2    2          1
3    3          1
4    4          1
5    5          1
6    1          2
7    2          2
8    3          2
9    4          2
10   5          2
11   1          3
12   2          3
13   3          3
14   4          3
15   5          3
```

Short explanation: `rep(x, each = 5)` is a vector which contains five repetitions of `x[1]` followed by five repetitions of `x[2]` etc.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. How would you go about writing this if you wanted an infinite number of repetitions?

Comment: why would you need an infinite number of repetitions? You can choose the number of repetitions according to the number of rows in your data.frame

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Sorry I thought I was looking at a Python question!**

I've imported it from excel because that was easiest for me but you create a DataFrame similarly from your .txt file.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(myDir + 'test.xlsx')

for i in range(0,len(df), 5):
    print(i)
    df.loc[i:i+5,'time stamp'] = 1 + i/5
```

Output:

```
    LED  time stamp      mean
0     1           1  0.000013
1     2           1  0.000037
2     3           1  0.000049
3     4           1  0.000060
4     5           1  0.000053
5     1           2  0.000014
6     2           2  0.000038
7     3           2  0.000051
8     4           2  0.000060
9     5           2  0.000054
10    1           3  0.000014
11    2           3  0.000038
12    3           3  0.000051
13    4           3  0.000060
14    5           3  0.000054
```

You will need to keep the index in the DataFrame.